# Add item to dictionary from previous dictionary (VBA)

Tags: excel, dictionary, vba

How do I do this? Here's some sample code I tried

```
Sub testing()
Dim n As Long
Dim dict As New Dictionary
Dim obj as MyClass

    For n = 1 To 10
        Set obj = New MyClass
        obj.value="I am an object" 'setting obj property
        dict.Add n, bcell
    Next n

    subDict.Add dict.Keys(1), dict.Items(1)'error here

End Sub
```

This throws an error:

`'Run-time error 424:`
`Object required`

Comment: You might have a bug in your code elsewhere, but VBA's syntax is reporting it here because it thinks the previous code is valid to a certain extent past where the real error lies. If possible, could you post the corpus of your code with all identifying information removed? The structure is important, but the names don't really matter.

Comment: @Shotgun Ninja Ok thanks, I edited post with a full sub I created.

Comment: You haven't made `subDict` anywhere.

Comment: oops, forgot option explicit hee hee

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Both the Item and the Key are required - that's why you were getting the 'argument not optional' error.

Now you're adding `bcell` which is neither declared nor instantiated. Did you mean to add `obj`?

```
Sub test()

    Dim Dict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim subDict As Scripting.Dictionary
    Dim obj As MyClass
    Dim n As Long

    Set Dict = New Scripting.Dictionary

    For n = 1 To 10
        Set obj = New MyClass
        obj.Value = "I'm object #" & n
        Dict.Add n, obj
    Next n

    Set subDict = New Scripting.Dictionary
    subDict.Add Dict.Keys(0), Dict.Items(0)

    Debug.Print subDict.Items(0).Value

End Sub
```

Note that dictionairy indeces start at 0 and not 1.

Comment: Alright thanks for all the info, I also forgot dictionaries indeces are different then collection's at the time. Also, I didn't have option explicit in my 'testing' Module. Now that I know this code works, hopefully I can figure out my other problem.